# What does the jQuery function $('#myelement').is('*') do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What does the following code do:

`$('#myelement').is('*')`

What does the asterisk signify? Since there is only one element, `#myelement`, I can't understand the point of using `is()`, which checks if an element matches a set of elements?

Comment: The * is the universal selector.

Comment: I don't think you guys understand... he's not asking what jQuery.is does.  He's asking what .is('*') does.

Comment: OK, I'll bite. Is it so hard to say `if (document.getElementById('myelement'))` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is some seriously existential JavaScript.

```
$('#myelement').is('*')
```

It will fail whenever `#myelement` doesn't exist, and return true otherwise.

Comment: And could be easily replaced just with `!! $('#myelement').length`, I suppose.

Comment: Exactly. Which is messed up because it will never return false, just throw a `TypeError`.

Comment: Ah, good suggestions by @pinvdb from an earlier comment. I ended up deleting my suggested way to do this (similiar to @raina77ow) because you can't call `.length` on null either, so we were making the same mistake the author of this code did.

Comment: And you were wrong. ) If element is not found, returned is an empty array - which is truthy value in JS, hence we cannot just do `!! $('selector')`.

Comment: @raina77ow I must have had a shadowed jQuery `$` selector. Here's what I was seeing: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s18/sh/d595fb97-863c-4b08-916f-c14b863c6839/ae48e1ce3c8adad4e78853b7f5f3c3a7/res/7cfe5608-1bfc-4a81-ba54-59ead75a7ea6/jquery_-_Google_Search-20120706-192633.jpg.jpg

Comment: An empty array is indeed a truthy in JS, and yet `[] == false //true`. I love JS...

Comment: @editor Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/EztJS/) to see how it behaves unshadowed. )

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/is/

Pretty much what it does well from my understanding of it at least, and how I tend to use it. Is return true or false on whatever its called on.

Example I have a checkbox that I want to make sure is checked before I submit my form via AJAX I would do something like

```
if( $('input#tosCheck').is(':checked') ){
    /*its checked submit form*/
}else{
    alert('Error');
}
```

All in all the link to the API from jQuery better describes it then I ever could, but I wanted to at least share an example of use to help you gauge some idea.

Answer (score 2):

Basically check to see if an element exists or not. Not the best method...

Comment: if ($("#mydiv").length > 0){
  // do stuff
}

Answer (score 2):

`is` checks the element fits the criteria. In this case, `"*"` means all elements.
So, it simply returns true if the previous selector returns anything.

Take a look here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/b7DwB/

Answer (score 2):

Can't say I've ever seen that jQuery code used before, but it seems to be a poor way of checking for the existence of an element. Since `*` is the universal selector, the expression in question will always return `true` if `#myelement` exists, otherwise it will return false.

I say this is a "poor" way of checking the existence of an element because you can simply check the length of the jQuery object instead:

```
$('#myelement').length > 0
```

I haven't done any testing, but I assume the above is faster since it doesn't have the overhead of the `is()` function call.

Comment: Think you meant `$('#myelement').length > 0`